# Получение this от начальной функции

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть вот такая функция:

```
function test(test) {
    this.test = test;
    $('#test').click(function(){
        alert(this.test);
    });
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить this.test, который мы передали при вызове?  
Вот пример на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezd3as70/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать лексическое замыкание на тот `this`:

```
function test(test) {
    this.test = test;
    var that = this; // замкнулись
    $('#test').click(function(){
        alert(that.test);
     });
}
```

Форк Вашего примера на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jz9apcho/1/)

Answer (score 2):

[Тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/149516/) описание принципов работы `this`; понимание работы этого механизма - уже половина ответа.
[Тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/149581/) продолжение темы - учимся привязывать и добираться до нужного контекста.

В JS часто применяют сохранение контекста `var self = this;` и обращаются к `self` как к нужному `this`.
Ответ [[@atwice](/users/12261/atwice)](/users/12261/atwice) хорошо это показал, я просто пару статеек для образовательной цели дал, которые дадут более обширное понимание вопроса.

Comment: @TheDoctor, Спасибо большое за предоставленные статьи.

Comment: @Mr_Epic, всегда пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

[bind](http://habrahabr.ru/post/199456/) - привязка контекста функции 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2Lm5o85/)

Answer (score 1):

this в функции вызванной не как конструктор указывает на `глобальный объект`. Это легко проверить:

```
function test(){
  return this === window;
}

console.log(test()); // true
```

Поэтому вызываем как конструктор, чтобы this указывал на созданный объект:

```
function Test(message) {
    this.message = message;
    this.init();
}

Test.prototype.init = function(){
    $('#test').click((function(){
      console.log(this.message);
    }).bind(this));
};

new Test('Hello');
```

Comment: Эмн, зачем ТС'у создавать прототипы и всё же байндить функцию, хотя решение уже есть и куда более лаконичное и простое, а значит, согласно принципу бритвы Оккама, правильное.

Comment: Я добавил пояснения к своему ответу.

Comment: Да как-то понятно зачем конструктор, непонятно зачем нарушать принцип бритвы :)

Comment: Да. Решение как бы есть, но оно содержит явную ошибку, потому что вопрос сам содержит ту же ошибку, которую я и постарался объяснить и показал более правильный пример.

Answer (score 0):

использовать стрелочную функцию.

```
function test(test) {
    this.test = test;
    $('#test').click(()=>{
        alert(this.test);
    });
}
```